# What is a resource in the resource.received context of events in Casperjs?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

What exactly is a resource in the [resource.received](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html?highlight=resource) event context of Casperjs ? What is its structure, I know it has a `.url` attribute but what else ? How can I learn more about it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CasperJS just forwards the native PhantomJS event handler [`onResourceReceived`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-received.html):

> The response metadata object contains these properties:
>
> - id : the number of the requested resource
> - url : the URL of the requested resource
> - time : Date object containing the date of the response
> - headers : list of http headers
> - bodySize : size of the received content decompressed (entire content or chunk content)
> - contentType : the content type if specified
> - redirectURL : if there is a redirection, the redirected URL
> - stage : "start", "end" (FIXME: other value for intermediate chunk?)
> - status : http status code. ex: 200
> - statusText : http status text. ex: OK

The easiest way is to just look into [casper.js](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/master/modules/casper.js) to see what they do.